# How is this handlebars variable binding being accomplished?

Tags: node.js, binding, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

**Summary**

A Handlebars tutorial is using a variable that is not explicitly bound. I am a handlebars novice, so my guess is that there is some implicit binding going on. I need to modify the code, but I don't know how this binding works or even what to search for.

---

I am building a nodejs app to interact with the microsoft graph API. Technically, I am using some [Microsoft tutorial code](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-nodeexpressapp/tree/main/demo/graph-tutorial) as a starting point. The tutorial is built using express and handlebars.

The tutorial is running and everything works.

Now I am modifying the code and I have not been able to discover how the handlebars variable binding works for the `user` variable. The `user` variable shows up in the views `index.hbs` and `layout.hbs`, for example:

```
{{#if user}}
  <h4>Welcome {{ user.displayName }}!</h4>
  <p>Use the navigation bar at the top of the page to get started.</p>
{{else}}
  <a href="/auth/signin" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Click here to sign in</a>
{{/if}}
```

I am new to handlebars and even after reading a few tutorials I still don't understand how this binding occurs. I found the following line in the `app.js` function `signIncomplete()`,

```
const user = await graph.getUserDetails(accessToken);
```

where `getUserDetails()` function creates the `user` object like this::

```
const user = await client.api('/me').get();
```

The function `signInComplete()` accesses `user.mail` and `user.userPrincipalName`, but there is no explicit code to expose this variable outside the function. Yet somehow the variable is bound when the handlebars templates are rendered. I inspected the `user` variable in the debugger so I know the data in the views must somehow come from `signInComplete()`. The few handlebars references I have read show how to bind an object to a compiled template, but that is not what is happening here.

How is this binding accomplished? As I mentioned, I am a handlebars novice, so if this is a special case or capability, I don't know what it is called or how to search for it. So a link to documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this would be done by the Passport JS middleware. You could try taking a look at http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-azure-ad/

Comment: @76484 Are you saying that Passport has functionality to bind data values into a handlebars render context? That sounds . . . surprising.  This answer seems like an explanation for how the `user` variable is created in `getUserDetails()`. That part makes sense to me and Passport is clearly the provider for that data. Also, I scanned through the page you linked, but I did not see any reference to Passport having any connection to Handlebars.

Comment: I see what you are saying. You want to know where Handlebars gets the reference to `user` set by Passport. On the NPM Page for the hbs library, I see a section entitled, "Exposing locals as template data"  (https://www.npmjs.com/package/hbs#exposing-locals-as-template-data) and in the tutorial code repo, in app.js, I see this line of code: `res.locals.user = req.user.profile;` (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-nodeexpressapp/blob/main/demo/graph-tutorial/app.js#L162). I think those links, together, provide your answer.

Comment: Thank you, you hit the nail on the head. If you want to compose an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding occurs on [line 162 of app.js](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-nodeexpressapp/blob/main/demo/graph-tutorial/app.js#L162) in the tutorial source code you linked to. The code is:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // Set the authenticated user in the
  // template locals
  if (req.user) {
    res.locals.user = req.user.profile;
  }
  next();
});
```

To understand what is happening here, we must cover a few things.

First, [Passport JS](http://www.passportjs.org/) is being used for authentication. Passport JS is an authentication middleware for Node applications. Basically, Passport authenticates the user based on some datum in the request Object. If the request can be authenticated, Passport will add the authenticated user data as a `user` property on the request (`req`) Object to be used by subsequent handlers.

In the code above, we can see that the `req.user` value that Passport has added is being accessed and assigned to a `res.locals.user`. [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.locals) is an Object in an Express app which allows for per-request data to be attached to the response (`res`) Object.

[hbs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hbs) is the Handlebars view engine for Express that is used in the tutorial. It is the hbs middleware that binds the values `res.locals` so that they are accessible to the Handlebars templates.